# Laravel 5.2 auth middleware on protected routes - show message

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using auth middleware in my routes.php as recommended to enforce login for protected routes.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
Route::resource('message', 'MessageController');
});
```

So when a protected route is requested if the user is not logged in then the login screen is displayed.

In this scenario I would like to add a  a to the login view saying something like-

'The page you have requested requires you to login.'

If possible I would also like to include the URL that the user has requested.

Any ideas as to how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just edit your `Authenticate` middleware to add a redirect message, which you can check for in your login screen:

```
redirect()->guest('/')->with('message', 'The page you have requested requires you to login.');
```

In your login screen:

```
if(Session::has('message')){
  echo Session::get('message');
}
```